# Перенос сайта на локальном сервере в декстоп приложение

Tags: javascript, php, css, html5, svg

Всем привет, это наверное будетсамый странный вопрос на форуме.

История такова, пишу дипломный проект на тему данную мне учебным учреждением «Приложение «Материально-техническое обеспечение кабинетов»на примере специальности информационных технологий».

Для написания выбрал языки указанные в метках.

Но вот незадача, в теме присутствует слово «Программа», что собственно не является сайтом, как ни странно.

Мой вопрос: есть ли какой нибудь сервис/способ переноса проекта в декстоп приложение с сохранением функционала.

Слышал про фреймворк электрон, не пробовал еще, тк решил сначала посоветоваться со знающими в этой теме людьми.

Вариант «лучше переписать» не подойдет, ведь как бы комично это не было, сдавать нужно завтра.

Comment: Может быть это будет вам полезно: https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: Вы ещё не видали тут самые странные вопросы.... К счастью для вас))

Comment: попробовал перенести, вроде визуал html остался, но назрел другой вопрос, как обращаться к id html компонентов? раньше обращался через document.getElementById. Сейчас так не работает

Comment: Честно скажу ни разу не работал с ним) Просто знаю что он есть) Лучше будет погуглить ну или на крайняк спросить тут с соответсвующими тегами, чтобы вам быстрее помогли))

Comment: @EzioMercer а не знаешь, как в принципе обращаться к id не используя при этом document. ?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. Можете прочитать этот вопрос, думаю будет полезно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron